# Vector initialized with size, impossible to clear

Tags: c++, vector, resize, garbage

I have this declaration of a multidimensional vector

```
std::vector< vector < vector  < ofxImage > > > front_objects;
```

Then I send it to my class when creating it:

```
Catalog_object * temp = new Catalog_object(&front_objects, numTag);
```

And then I perform the following:

```
Catalog_object::Catalog_object(vector< vector < vector  < ofxImage > > > * _front_objects, int numTag) {
    front_objects=_front_objects;
    if (front_objects->size()<numTag+1) {
        front_objects->resize(numTag+1);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to populate the main **front_objects** with vectors of **ofxImages** from the Catalog_objects, which might share some vectors of vectors of ofxImages.

The problem is that "sometimes" the vector is initialized with garbage and when trying to clear it with

```
front_objects[numTag].resize(2);
```

the program crashes with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

When resizing it with resize(), shouldnt it be filled with empty vectors?

Thanks

Marc

**UPDATE**

I tried doing like this but I get "uninitialized reference member 'Catalog_object::front_objects'".

```
Catalog_object::Catalog_object(vector< vector < vector  < ofxImage > > > & _front_objects, int numTag) { // CHANGED * FOR &
    std::vector< vector  < vector < ofxImage > > > & front_objects; // CHANGED * FOR &
    front_objects=_front_objects;
    if (front_objects.size()<numTag+1) {
        front_objects.resize(numTag+1);
    }
    front_objects[numTag].resize(2);
}


std::vector< vector < vector  < ofxImage > > > front_objects;
Catalog_object * temp = new Catalog_object(front_objects, numTag); // REMOVED &
```

Comment: Tangential comment: This is really a canonical example of when typedefs would be a good thing!

Comment: I am a c++ newbie, I'll check typedefs

Comment: I just learnt how to use typedefs. Very easy and useful! http://www.functionx.com/cpp/keywords/typedef.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely in

```
front_objects[numTag].resize(2);
```

`numTag` holds an invalid index.

Without the relevant code is difficult to say. Effectively you're saying that every time you walk into your kitchen you hear a strange sound. The picture of the cat that's stuck in between two somethings makes it likely that it's the cat, but could be something else. :-)

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Thanks Alf, but I already took care of that when I did front_objects->resize(numTag+1); , or am I wrong? I'm worried that I could be messing with the pointers ("pointing to the wrong places")

Comment: @Mark: oh `****` (censored). You mean that that resize call is within your constructor, where `front_objects` has been declared as a pointer? Uh oh. If so then you're using that pointer as an array, and then here's how to fix: pass it by reference instead of as a pointer. That is, replace your formal param `*` with a `&`, and replace `->` with `.`, and drop the address operator in the invocation. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Thanks Alf. Yes, the resize is inside of the Catalog_object constructor, maybe in the update that I have made to my code is clearer. I tried to apply your suggestions, but I get an "uninitialized reference member" error. I'm not good at pointers yet, so probably I have done something else wrong now! :S
My intention is that all the modifications are made always to the same front_objects

Comment: @Marc: if I understand this correctly, in the original code `front_objects` was a member variable, of type pointer to vector of vector of vector of something. Presumably you still have that member variable. To make things simple, rename the member, e.g. `p_front_objects`. Then initialize it as address of the formal argument. You can still use a local reference declaration for convenience. If so then the local reference needs to be initialized. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: thanks for your help, but I saw that I had several problems that made me restructure the code. I finally made the vector a static member of the Catalog_object class, which made things easier and I didn't encounter the problem above. However that's something that I'll have to chech again at some point!
Thank you for your patience, 
Marc